# printf(%s), string issues... Essentially the %s is causing a line overwrite.

Tags: c

Okay, to get a reasonable picture of what's happening...

I'm reading the data from a csv table into a two-dimensional array like this:

```
tableFile = fopen(argv[4], "r");
char tableArray[30][50][256];
char c;
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while(c != EOF){

    c = fgetc(tableFile);

    switch(c)
    {
        case ',':
            tableArray[i][j++][k]='\0';
            k=0;
            break;
        case '\n':
            tableArray[i++][j][k]='\0';
            j=0;
            k=0;
            break;
        default:
            tableArray[i][j][k++] = c;
            break;
    }
} //end file transfer

fclose(tableFile);
```

After reading in the file, I do a bunch of junk that's irrelevant, but the ISSUE is that when I go to print something from data acquired from said table printf freaks out.

For example, if I were to try and say something like.

```
 char *string = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
 string = tableArray[9][46];
 printf("What the heck is going on with this string %s ", string);
```

See that space AFTER the %s? It would actually overwrite the "W" and the printf would show something like " hat the heck is going on with this strong HELLO"

Any ideas?!?!

Thanks!

Comment: Minor point: your `malloc` is unnecessary and is leaking memory.

Comment: Windows ENTERs are composed of `"\r\n"`. Remove the `'\r'` from the output string.

Comment: `getc` returns an **int** not a char.

Comment: I think you are pretty new with C because I think you want to copy string from tableArray[9][46] instead of pointing to it. What does printf say if you use just `printf("%s\n", string);` ?

Comment: When you hit EOF, your code goes into the `default:` statement and writes the value of `EOF` into `tableArray`.  You need to an explicit case for `EOF` in the switch statement to avoid that, or add a check for `EOF` immediately after `fgetc` returns.

Comment: @sixlettervariables If I don't have the malloc then it gives me a seg fault error.

Comment: @Meshach: from the code you posted that is not possible as the next line overwrites the pointer stored in `string`. You are not using the allocated memory, therefore it is a NO-OP. You could set: `string = null` on the line before `tableArray` and nothing would change. You have a problem elsewhere if removing the malloc causes a seg fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your read-in line ends with a `'\r'`. You should handle the `'\r'` case specially in your `switch`.

Comment: Also note that `printf` is buffered and usually needs `\n` to flush.

Comment: Apparently it was just that simple. Amazing. All I had to do was add a couple of cases to the switch which essentially ignored carriage returns and EOF and it was fine.

Bleh! I spent so long trying to figure out what was going on. 

Several of you were on this track. Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 2):

The string is probably something like `"HELLO\r "`.  Carriage returns move the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The file has CR (`'\r'`) characters and you are putting them at the end of your substrings.

Answer (score 0):

How are lines terminated in your input file?

If you are using a Windows end-of-line conversion, that is `\r\n`, you have to skip `\r` too in your switch.